# git merge-base with sparse checkout and --no-tags

Tags: git

I have a script running on a git repository which does some analysis prior to merging a pull request.

The script performs

```
git merge-base master HEAD
```

to determine the "deviation point" commit.

However, the local git repo was formed using a sparse checkout in a Jenkins workspace and **this configuration cannot be changed**. It is obtained via:

- `git init`
- then a few `git fetch --no-tags`
- `git config core.sparsecheckout`
- `git checkout -f <hash>`

Then there is the following error:

```
fatal: Not a valid object name master
```

The output of `git log` looks like this:

```
commit 84887... (HEAD, origin/PR-424)
Author: Me
Date:   Today

    blah blah

commit 54adf...
Merge: 889aefe 46630ae
Author: Me
Date:   Yesterday

    Merge pull request #123 in blah blah to master
    (this is the result of merging the most recent pull request
    prior to the currently open PR)
        
commit 46630ae...
Author: Me
Date:   Last week

    ...
```

If I run my script in a full (non-sparse) checkout of the repository, the result of `git merge-base` is `54adf...` and the semantic significance of this that it is the state of the master branch after the most recent merge.

How do I get the same information (the "deviation point") when the checkout is sparse?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a sparse-checkout or not. It fails because `master` is not present in the repository.

Comment: @ElpieKay I have updated the question to clarify. Can you please explain a little more? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jenkins build may clone/fetch parts of the refs for lower time and storage cost. As it checks out a detached HEAD by `git checkout -f <hash>`, I guess it just fetches the PR only. It doesn't fetch `master` and/or `master` is not created in the local repository, and therefore `master` is unknown in the repository, like an undefined variable. To use an undefined variable raises errors.

In the script try `git fetch origin +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master; git merge-base origin/master HEAD` instead. It fetches `master` from the remote repository and stores it as `refs/remote/origin/master` or the short form `origin/master`.

If the job allows multiple builds concurrently, I suggest you replace `origin/master` with `origin/master_somerandomwords` in the commands for each build and remove it by `git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/master_somerandomwords` in the end, to avoid conflicts that multiple fetch processes try to update the same `origin/master`.